# How to configure MongoEngine for Heroku

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I have postgresql as my main database and I am using mongodb for 'audit-trail' purposes.

I am using `mongoengine` for my django app.

In localhost, in order to connect to mongodb database I did this:

```
connect('dbname')
```

and that is it, as documentation suggested.

But this is not working in heroku.

I added `MongoLab` add-on to my heroku application and they gave me this connections string:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds037622.mongolab.com:37622/heroku_app30998840
```

Then I tried this:

```
connect('heroku_app30998840', username='username', password='pwd', host='mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds037622.mongolab.com:37622/heroku_app30998840')
```

This did not work either.

How can I fix this?

Or maybe I should use something else other than `MongoEngine`? some other better way?

Comment: Is it possible to provide an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what worked for me:

```
connect('heroku_app30998840', username='username', password='pwd', host='@ds037622.mongolab.com:37622')
```

i.e remove everything except host and port number in `host` part.